# intercept Android Bluetooth Camera Shutter in Background Service

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an Camera Shutter for my Android phone.

It is an bluetooth device which has one button and connect as a bluetooth keyboard to the phone. If button get pressed it sends keycode.enter and volume up.

My question is is it possible to intercept its message in an background service?

So far I read the keyevent is not available in background.
But can I intercept the Bluetooth changes or something else?
Some Ideas?

I would like to give a notification on press of the button. When its running as a background service.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

As you already know background services cannot listen for KeyEvents [View.OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener)

But you can handle [BluetoothSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket) events as you would with a standard [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket)

I think the [Android Bluetooth Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) page is a good starting point

Good luck

Comment: Oh Ok nice, I will check that out.

Comment: @shortQuestion Were you able to solve this problem with BluetoothSocket?